# Java - Illegal address in string ``'' validation

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I need some help, I am working with javax.mail. I have a list "listDirectorio", it contains all the email address, but there are some records that has not email address then I get the Illegal address in string ``'' exception. I tried to validate the null email address with:

```
if(listDirectorio.get(i).getCorreo() != null && !listDirectorio.get(i).getCorreo().equals(""))
```

but I keep getting the address exception

Here's my code:

```
String[] toEmails= null;
List<Directorio> to = DirectorioDAO.getListDirectorio(selectCta);
List<Directorio> listDirectorio=new ArrayList<Directorio>();        
listDirectorio.addAll(to);
 if (listDirectorio.size()>0) {
  int size = listDirectorio.size();
  toEmails = new String[size];      
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
   if(listDirectorio.get(i).getCorreo() != null && !listDirectorio.get(i).getCorreo().equals("")){
    toEmails[i] = listDirectorio.get(i).getCorreo();
    }                   
   }
  }
```

Comment: Paulina where do you have the exception?

Comment: Try to find out the addresses that fail during validation check. Now check whether your if condition rejects those addresses.

Comment: assume it fails the validation, then your `toEmails[i]` is null since you don't assign it anything

Comment: @nachokk here: toEmails[i] = listDirectorio.get(i).getCorreo();, gets all email address but there are some null, then I get the Illegal address in string ``'' because is null.

Comment: @vandale No, it's not null, example: I have toEmails[0] = example.gmail.com toEmails[1] = null and then because toEmails[1] is null i get that exception

Comment: @NishantShreshth Ok, I will try and write what happend.

Comment: @vandale Exactly, that's what I tried to avoid with if (listDirectorio.get(i).getCorreo() != null && !listDirectorio.get(i).getCorreo().equals("")) but does not work!.

Comment: fist put the correct strings in an `ArrayList<String>` since you don't know the number of valid strings. Then call `toArray()` and store that in `toEmails`